# How to draw a trajectory on Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to trace the trajectory from the point of data in **Android**.

what method should I use for this ?

to know the displacement of an object I need to determine a trace from the point that I have already determined on Android

Comment: Have you got any skills in math or physics?

Comment: I just want the method to draw from the point that I possess a trajectory on Android

Comment: You could look into OpenGL and look at the graphics side of things

Comment: I want to draw the path from the position I have already calculated i mean with coordinates x and Y can you help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/DrawPoints.html it shows the basics of drawing, all you need to do is draw a whole bunch of lines right? all you need is a xi and yi and then a xf and yf to draw it.

Comment: that's exactly what I use Canvas and OnDraw, but I have a problem with the update of X and Y: (because I created a sub activity that deals with drawing;
Look my idea is to create a button and a TextView that displays the X and Y position and then when I click on my button the other activity begins (I use Intent) I see that it drew the Poins but stops like he no longer receiving the X and Y coordinates of the main activity: (